# Raspberry Pi Pico: Hardware UART Tx not working

Tags: c, c++, rp2040, raspberry-pi-pico

I recently got a Raspberry Pi Pico as an evaluation board for the RP2040. When I tried to use hardware UART, I found that it would not send data.

To find out what was going on, I used an LED on the Tx pin and found that it would flicker once then remain on until powered off. This happened no matter the port or Tx pin.

After further testing, I found that the LED turned on only after `gpio_set_function(pin, GPIO_FUNC_UART);` was called.

I have no idea what to do about this.

FYI:

- To test UART, I am using an Arduino MKR WiFi 1010 as a peer, as it is also a 3.3V based board.
- The Arduino's UART does work
- The Pico does function in other areas, such as GPIO.
- I have tested this on both ports and on every option for UART pins, as well as multiple baud rates (9600, 115200, etc.).
- I uploaded the code using the earlephilhower Arduino core

Code (Pico SDK):

```c
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "hardware/uart.h"

int main () {
    uart_init(uart0, 9600);
    gpio_set_function(0, GPIO_FUNC_UART);
    gpio_set_function(1, GPIO_FUNC_UART);

    while (1) {
        uart_putc(uart0, 'a');
        sleep_ms(500);
    }
}
```

Code (earlephilhower core):

```cpp
void setup (void) {
    Serial1.begin(9600);
}

void loop (void) {
    Serial1.print("a");
    delay(500);
}
```

Comment: How are you writing to the UART?  printf?  Can you show your code?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your code.

Comment: done. (just examples, I tried variations on pins, baud rates, and ports)

Comment: I believe with the Pico SDK printf defaults to outputting on UART0, have you tried that?

Comment: As pico sdk stdio is a separate module, I have no idea how to include it with the earlephilhower core. VSCode is not an option. Also, printf would default to that as it is the default UART port.